# Always open new files in the same window

Tags: window, files

When I open a file externally - through the terminal or the file manager GUI, it opens in a new window.

How can I always open a file in a new buffer of an existing emacs session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not too clear. Is what you want to open Emacs, from outside Emacs, to edit a file?

If so, use program/command `emacsclient` or `emacs` followed by a file name. See the Emacs manual, node [Action Arguments](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Action-Arguments.html) and perhaps node [Emacs Server](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Emacs-Server.html).

Comment: If I do `emacs file1.txt` followed by `emacs file2.txt` in the terminal, two separate windows of emacs open file1 and file2 respectively. I would like to check that if an existing window is already open (for file1 in this case), open the next file (file2 in this case) in a new buffer of the current window.

Comment: `emacsclient`, if you want to reuse the same Emacs session. (And I think maybe you mean "frame" instead of Emacs "window" and Emacs "window" instead of "buffer".)